# TB_CircularSlider not working properly in separate uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Has anyone used TB_CircularSlider in your project?  I want to show a circular slider in my own view but the slider is not coming properly

Here is my code in view controller

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    TBCircularSlider *slider = [[TBCircularSlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sliderView.frame.size.width, self.sliderView.frame.size.height)];

    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.sliderView addSubview:slider];
}
}
```

I've one view in storyboard and I want the slider to display in that view but it's not coming properly.

Comment: What's the actual size of your sliderView?
Because TBCircularSlider have static height and width.
Go through this [link](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/) . Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Slider view height is 50 and leading trailing and bottom is 0

Comment: I had given the frame in initWithFrame. Where do we need to change the static height and width

Comment: can you give some more code for your TBCircularSlider class so i can check.....as i have been using this and it works for me

Comment: @Dhivya check the link that I have mentioned in my previous comment. A brief description is there about "TB_CircularSlider".

Comment: @Zck I want the slider to come inside the view which has width and height 200. But it's exceeding the view and going out of the view

Comment: @Dhivya can you let me know what radius you are using.? or if you can edit your question with some code will be great ,or pls attach your output..,so i can go through